# Accessibility Service start

Tags: android

I created an app that implements an accessibility service. If the user has enabled my service, he can start it, for example with startService(), and he should not be able to do so if it is not enabled.

I tried with startService(), but accessibility service was already running when I enabled it. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility service is controlled by Android system, you cannot control it's start/stop by yourself. Even if you call `stop()` method on it, the service will get restarted automatically.

However, you can call `AccessibilityService.setServiceInfo(new AccessibilityServiceInfo())` to ignore accessibility event for your app.